# Cookie values consistently returning null

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm attempting to use a prompt to have someone enter a value, make that value into a cookie, then have a link that will redirect that person to a second page where their cookie value would be displayed. The issue I'm running into is that the cookie in question continues to be returned null, no matter what I input. Any help would be appreciated!

This is meant to be a Javascript code.

**First Page (Prompt Page)**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Handlers</title>
<script>
         function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
                if (days) {
                        var date = newDate();
                        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
                        var expires = date.toGMTString ();//code
                }
                else var expires = "";
                cookieString = name + "=" + escape(value);
                if (expires) cookieString += ";expires=" + expires;
                if (path) cookieString += "; path=" + escape (path);
                if (domain) cookieString += "; domain=" + escape (domain);
                if (secure) cookieString += "; secure";
                document.cookie = cookieString
                                
                }

function getCookie(name) {
                var nameEquals = name + "=";
                var crumbs = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < crumbs.length; i++) {
                                var crumb = crumbs[i];
                                if (crumb.indexOf(nameEquals) == 0) {
                                                return unescape(crumb.substring(nameEquals.length, crumb.length));
                                                //code
                                }
                }
                return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
                createCookie(name,"",-1);
                //code
}
</script>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var cookievalue = prompt("Cookie Value:");
        createCookie("myCookieData", cookievalue);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<a href="/cookietest2">Go to Cookie Test Page 2</a>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Second Page (Display Cookie Page)**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Cookie Testing</title>
     <head>
    <script>
function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
                if (days) {
                        var date = newDate();
                        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
                        var expires = date.toGMTString ();//code
                }
                else var expires = "";
                cookieString = name + "=" + escape(value);
                if (expires) cookieString += ";expires=" + expires;
                if (path) cookieString += "; path=" + escape (path);
                if (domain) cookieString += "; domain=" + escape (domain);
                if (secure) cookieString += "; secure";
                document.cookie = cookieString
                                
                }

function getCookie(name) {
                var nameEquals = name + "=";
                var crumbs = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < crumbs.length; i++) {
                                var crumb = crumbs[i];
                                if (crumb.indexOf(nameEquals) == 0) {
                                                return unescape(crumb.substring(nameEquals.length, crumb.length));
                                                //code
                                }
                }
                return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
                createCookie(name,"",-1);
                //code
}
    </script>

    
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your cookie value: " + getCookie("myCookieData");
    }
</script>

   </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/hour">Back to Cookie Test Page 1</a><br />
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In addition, if anyone can give tips on to how to add a button to the second page to delete the cookies from the first page, that would also be greatly appreciated! But for now, I'd just like to figure out why my cookies keep being returned null. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are not allowed in local files on some browsers. So if you're using local files - try uploading those files to a server and trying again. Works for me.

To add a cookie delete button you can use:

```
<input type="button" onClick="deleteCookie('myCookieData')" />
```